# Is it bad to have accommodation changes when being interviewed by UK airport immigration

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

My boyfriend had his UK visitor visa application accepted which was a huge relief, and I have since booked small trips within the UK for when he comes.

We put down on the application that he'd be staying at a hotel in a local city but have since changed the plans to him staying at my house or my father's house since it's more cost-effective. Would this be a red flag for the immigration officers? We have bookings for some short stay hotels that we can print out but we're a bit nervous that this change will come across badly and have no idea what the best way he can explain it to them is. He is visiting from Oman where he is studying if that helps.

Comment: You all should be 100% certain of where he will stay _before_ he gets on the plane. Changing accommodations is not necessarily a problem, but not being sure of your accommodations _is_ a problem.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thank you for the response! It's preferable that he can stay with me but if that looks bad to the immigration officer then we can easily arrange for him to stay with my father, hence the flexibility. I'm just hoping to do whatever is safest at this point!

Comment: @wacomhelp Given you told them he’s your boyfriend in the application and the premise of the application was presumably to visit you, it might look a bit odd if he weren’t staying with you :-)

Comment: And the border agent will see he has a motive to stay back in UK because he has a girlfriend here, so better keep things watertight.

Answer (score 4):

> Would this be a red flag for the immigration officers?

No.

Advance accommodation arrangements are not required by the UK for visa applications. Any accommodation details that you provided at that stage do not have to match the new details.

As long as there is a reasonable arrangement, and you don't make up things at the border; This should not be a problem at all.

If the new bookings that you have are valid bookings, there is no harm in presenting them. If he will be staying at your father's place, there is no harm in mentioning that if asked.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a huge weight off our shoulders, I really appreciate it